# How to format a Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date, bootstrap-datepicker

i am using bootstrap dateTimePicker.

Because the dateTimePicker works, the input needs to be in this format: 
`30/07/2019 23:59:59`.

The dateTimePicker works fine, i initialize it with this function and it works as i want:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control " id="datepick2"  name="transaction_date_from"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var d = new Date();
$("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),23,59,59,00),
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
        sideBySide: true,
        showTodayButton: true,
        showClear: true,
    });
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({format: 'LT'}).on('dp.show', function(event) {
        $(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget").find('.btn[data-action="togglePeriod"]').hide();
    });
```

What i'm trying to do is that i have a `<button>` that when is clicked it has to restore to the "defaultDate" the dateTimePicker. 
What i've tried is:

```js
 var d = new Date();
 var dateTo = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),23,59,59,00);
 $("#datepick2").val(dateTo);
```

but instead of getting the same result as when i initialize the dateTimePicker, i get

`Tue Jul 30 2019 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)`.

So, my question is: **how can i format the date as i want? Is there a bootstrap function that can do it?**

Is there some function that can do it? I've seen the other question but it don't seem to answer my question.

Comment: You could use MomentJS. It is a very useful script when using dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native javascript you'd have to manually convert the date to the desired format e.g.

```js
function formatMonth(month){
  month +=1;
  return month > 9 ? month : "0"+month;
}

const d = new Date();
const toDate = `${d.getDate()}/${formatMonth(d.getMonth())}/${d.getFullYear()} 23:59:59`
console.log(toDate)
```

However it would way easier and more readable to just use a library like `momentjs`

```js
const dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss';
console.log(moment().set({hours: 23, minutes: 59, seconds: 59}).format(dateFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `momentjs` worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using a library just for that seems a little overkill, you can use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: false}).replace(/,/, ''));
```

Though, if you are doing a lot of time manipulation `moment.js` is a great library.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I don't advocate packages for simple & benign tasks but when it comes to datetimes in JS, I strongly suggest looking into then [**date-fns**](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) package.

It's a [30kB/7kB package](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=date-fns) and covers most (if not all of your needs).

> how can i format the date as i want? Is there a bootstrap function that can do it?

For your specific formatting, checkout its [`format()`](https://date-fns.org/docs/format) method. You can even use it without importing/requiring the whole thing!

Here's a running demo: [runkit/b2e2y529fo87](https://runkit.com/embed/b2e2y529fo87)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#setDate').click(function(){
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',defaultDate:new Date()})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
   
<button id="setDate">Init Date</button>
 <input type="text" class="form_datetime"/>
```